# ParseExact doesn't recognize "Mdyyyy" format

Tags: powershell

I have strings with dates that look like this:  '812021'.  (That would be Aug 1, 2021)

That's the "**Mdyyyy**" format, and I've double-checked this with [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#dSpecifier).

- M --> Month, no leading zeros, 1-12
- d --> Day of month, no leading
  zeros, 1-31
- yyyy --> 4-digit year

HOWEVER, when I try to `ParseExact()`, I get an error if I don't supply a leading zero.  Unfortunately, the source content will not have leading zeros.

**Why won't my date format work?  `Mdyyyy`?**

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('812021', 'Mdyyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

<#
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:18 char:1
+ [DateTime]::ParseExact('812021', 'Mdyyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCu ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
#>
```

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('08012021', 'Mdyyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)

# Sunday, August 1, 2021 12:00:00 AM
```

**UPDATE -- ADDITIONAL EXAMPLES**

Aug 1, 2021, 4:01:31 PM
`MdyyyyHms`

Fails:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('812021160132', 'MdyyyyHms',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Does not fail:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('08012021160132', 'MdyyyyHms', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: OK. How would you distinguish between the first of December and the twenty first of January? ;-)   ... both would be `1212021`  ... I think you would need a delimiter between the month and the day

Comment: `1212021` Good Point!  You couldn't with this format.  The full actual format is `MddyyyyHms`.  The vendor has all the dates in the filenames.  I'm trying to find and delete items older than a specific date.  I need to think about this more.

Comment: That would mean that there are leading zeros for the days ...

Comment: You have my word, there are no leading zeros -- for the Month, or Date.... I'm updating this with two more examples with the full format.

Comment: So it is a typo in your comment, isn't it? You just wrote `MddyyyyHms` in it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo.  Definitely `MdyyyyHms`.  Apologies.  Your point is very good about `1212021`.  Time wouldn't matter in that case, probably.  I hope the vendor can change the prefix.

Comment: I think you need at least either leading zeros for the days or a delimiter between the months and the days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236111/discussion-between-namedarray-and-olaf).

Answer (score 1):

While you're waiting for your vendor to change the prefix, you could correct these date strings yourself:

```
$dateStamp = '812021'
$date = if ($dateStamp -match '\d{6}') { 
            '0{0}0{1}' -f ($dateStamp -split '^(.)' -ne '')
            # or something like: '0{0}0{1}' -f $dateStamp.Substring(0,1), $dateStamp.Substring(1) 
        }
        else { $dateStamp }
[DateTime]::ParseExact($date, 'MMddyyyy', [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: I like the recommendation to extract the specific digits if a specific pattern was detected :)